# Anchor init PDA fails with "signer privilege escalated"

Tags: anchor, pda

*I probably am doing something really stupid but this basic thing doesn't seem to work for me for this scenario. I checked the [other](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/688/anchor-initialize-account-with-pda-as-payer) [questions](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/861/can-anyone-create-an-account-at-a-specific-pda-address/908#908) similar to this one but they are either different scenarios or their answers didn't help me.*

I have these instruction accounts:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateProfile<'info> {
    pub state: Account<'info, State>,

    #[account(
        init,
        payer = user, 
        space = 60,
        seeds = [state.to_account_info().key.as_ref(), user.key.as_ref()],
        bump,
    )]
    pub user_profile: Account<'info, UserProfile>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

The actual `create_profile()` function is empty, i.e. `Ok(())`. When running a test against it, it fails with:

```
Program Fg6PaFpoGXkYsidMpWTK6W2BeZ7FEfcYkg476zPFsLnS invoke [1]
Program log: Instruction: CreateProfile
HCrVyydLF9CgiqeQNxq9dyxUswJF7KkYGurFcj2E7gfh's signer privilege escalated
Program Fg6PaFpoGXkYsidMpWTK6W2BeZ7FEfcYkg476zPFsLnS consumed 7512 of 200000 compute units
Program Fg6PaFpoGXkYsidMpWTK6W2BeZ7FEfcYkg476zPFsLnS failed: Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account
```

The only CPI call is the one Anchor does to create the account, due to `init` constraint. I know that to create an account, you'll need two signers: the payer and the new account itself. I am not quite sure what happens when the latter is a PDA.

This is the code that is testing it:

```
// omitted: state initialised in an earlier transaction

const userA = Keypair.generate();

// omitted: airdop for userA

const [pdaA] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
  [state.publicKey.toBytes(), userA.publicKey.toBytes()],
  program.programId
);

await program.methods
  .create_profile()
  .accounts({
    state: state.publicKey,
    user_profile: pdaA,
    user: userA.publicKey,
  })
  .signers([userA])
  .rpc({ skipPreflight: true });
```

From the code above, it doesn't look like I am sending in the wrong seeds neither.

Comment: I even changed the seed to be just a static text in both the program and unit test but no dice.

Answer (score 2):

The `signer privilege escalated` error tells us that your instruction is making a CPI but the signer it receives is not what it expects.

In this particular instance what's happening is that a CPI is being made to the `System Program` to create your `user_profile` account. Every account signs its own creation so that tells us that the signer we're concerned with in this case is `user_profile`. The `user_profile` you generate on your client side does not match what the anchor program generates and expects.

Do this instead:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateProfile<'info> {
    ...
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = user, 
        space = 60,
        seeds = [state.key().as_ref(), user.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
    )]
    pub user_profile: Account<'info, UserProfile>,
    ...
}
```

and in your client:

```
const [pdaA, _] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
  [state.publicKey.toBuffer(), userA.publicKey.toBuffer()],
  program.programId
);
```